# Iterating 'forEach' member with a role

Tags: foreach, collections, discord, discord.js

I have found several posts that seem to be trying to solve this problem, but none of the solutions / attempts I have seen will work for me.

I have a 'role' which my bot fetches successfully.  On command I want the bot to then go through each of the members with that role and give them additional roles.

It simply will not work, so (for testing / debugging purposes) I currently have the following code:

```
const teamCaptainRole = await message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Team Captain");
console.log(teamCaptainRole.members)
await teamCaptainRole.members.forEach(member => {
  console.log(member)
});
```

Previous 'console logs' of "teamCaptainRole" have shown me that I am successfully fetching the role.  The console log of "teamCaptainRole.members" returns:

```
Collection [Map] {}
```

I have done googling around these words, but just find myself on a wild goose chase - I cannot find a way to dig down into this Map / Collection.  I do not have any prior experience of working with maps, but arrays and objects I understand well.  The 'forEach' never seems to trigger, but also doesn't throw any errors - simply nothing happens.  Right now I would just love to be able to see a series of console logs of members that have that role so that I know the forEach is working.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Team Captain");
let giveRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Enter Role Here");
let users = role.members.map(m => message.guild.member(m.user));
for(let user of users) {
   user.roles.add(giveRole);
}
```

`role` -> The role where we will search the users from.
`giveRole` -> The role we will give all members that have `role`.
`users` -> The users who have `role`.

You could use `users.forEach()` as well but I used a basic for-loop. We map those users who have the role, but as an GuildMember Object, so that we can add `giveRole` in the for-loop.

Comment: Hey, thank you, but I still can't get this to work.  I have set it to:

`const teamCaptainRole = await message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Team Captain");
const teamCaptains = await teamCaptainRole.members.map(m => message.guild.member(m.user));
console.log(teamCaptains);`

and the console log gives me:
`[]`

therefore, forEach and a normal 'for' loop do not achieve anything.

Comment: Good then it works! Your guild just don't have any users with that role ^^

Comment: Funnily enough I'm competent enough to check things like that - the role it fetches (checked with console log, it is the correct role) has 14 members with that role.

Comment: Hm okay, what is the output of  `user` if you use my for-loop?

Comment: It is working for me btw and usually it should work in general.

Comment: If I use:  `let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Team Captain");
            let giveRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Test Role");
            let users = role.members.map(m => message.guild.member(m.user));
            for(let user of users) {
                console.log(user)
            }` and I do console logs for Team Captain and the 'Temp Role' these are both correct (correct colour, permissions etc.) and then a console log of "users" gives `[]`  and therefore, the console log in the for-loop is never triggered.